# Parse Error on Input ‘where’

Tags: haskell, where-clause

I am trying to "solve" the Pell's equation for a given `d`:  `x^2 - d * y^2 = 1`, or at least I want to get the minimal `x > 0` which will solve the equation. So far so good. Here is my Haskell code

```
minX :: Integer -> Integer
minX n  | isSquare n = 1
        | otherwise  = minXRec [0,1,intSqrt n] [1,0,1] 0 1 (intSqrt n) n

minXRec :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
minXRec (p0:p1:p2:x) (q0:q1:q2:y) m d a n
    | p2*p2 - n*q2*q2 == 1 = p2
    | minXRec [p1, p2, newA*p2+p1] [q1, q2, newA*q2+q1] newM newD newA n
    where
        newM = d*a-m
        newD = quot (n-newM*newM) d
        newA = quot (intSqrt n + newM) newD
```

The logic of the code should work fine, but on compiling I get

```
PE66.hs:28:9: parse error on input ‘where’
```

Which does not provide me with enough information to fix the problem.
I already tried to put this in an `let .. in ..` style but I, like this, did not get it to work.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second guard of minXRec you don't have a conditional test. You will need to change

```
| minXRec [p1, p2, a*p1+p0] [q1, q2, a*q1+q0] newM newD newA n
```

to most probably

```
| otherwise = minXRec [p1, p2, a*p1+p0] [q1, q2, a*q1+q0] newM newD newA n
```

Comment: facepalm. 3 minutes left to mark your answer as the solution :D